# Why RSpec fails with TypeError when an expectation does't match?

Tags: ruby, rspec

When I run `rspec` with an example that will pass, everything is fine.
But when the expectation doesn't match I got a weird `TypeError` instead of a useful message about the difference between expected and actual value.

**Given**

- ruby 2.3.1p112
- rspec 3.5.2
- a spec helper just as being generated by `rspec —init`

**When**

```
describe "Basics" do
  it "runs rspec successfully" do
    x = true
    expect(x).to be(true)
  end
end
```

**Then** everything is fine

```
Finished in 0.00286 seconds (files took 0.09671 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

**BUT** when I change x to false, thus the match fails

**When**

```
describe "Basics" do
  it "runs rspec successfully" do
    x = false
    expect(x).to be(true)
  end
end
```

**Then**

```
Failures:

  1) Basics runs rspec successfully
     Failure/Error: expect(x).to be(true)

     TypeError:   <——— 
       superclass must be a Class (Module given)
     # ./spec/lib/basic_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.06168 seconds (files took 0.09715 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

I would expect an output like

```
  lhs: false
  rhs: true
```

instead of this TypeError.

What's wrong here?

Comment: I think you can only use `expect(x).to be` or `expect(x).not_to be` In all other cases you use operators with be like  `expect(x).to be < 3` I think.

Comment: There are also these constructs, for testing truthy/falsey rather than true/false: `expect(x).to be_truthy` ; `expect(x).to be_falsey`

Answer (score 0):

the reason for this was the following line in my gem file

```
gem "prettyprint"
```

I removed it from Gemfile and everything works as expected.
As I figured out, it's possible to use `pp some_object` without using any gem.